# Scaling Popup box using CSS, Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating popup box in my website homepage. i refered this code from one of other thread from stack, it works as per my requirement.

Below code will gives me the correct popup box. But i need to make the popup box to be 1/4 th of page, is that  possible to do?

```
<div id="boxes">
<div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
  <img src="images/coupon2011.jpg" width="507" height="300" /> 
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/closelabel.gif" width="66" height="22" /></a>
</div>
<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
<div style="width: 1478px; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
// Check if cookie exists
if (Cookies.get('popunder')) {
    return;
}

var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect     
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

// Set cookie to be sure the popover activated again
Cookies.set('popunder', '1');

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});      

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

});

</script>
```

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

To set something as 1/4th of the **viewport**, which is pretty much the page, you need to set the property `width: 25vw` onto the popup, and then use some technique to center the modal, of course. If that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
// Check if cookie exists
if (Cookies.get('popunder')) {
    return;
}

var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height()/2;
var maskWidth = $(window).width()/2;

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect     
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

// Set cookie to be sure the popover activated again
Cookies.set('popunder', '1');

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});      

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

});

</script>
```